# Paytm PHP function mcrypt_get_block_size() deprecated issue

Tags: php, paytm

I have been using the paytm library for one of my app. I need to test a new version of my app on another server. Hence I have uploaded the app on server, but when I try to add money to my wallet, I get the following error -

> Severity: 8192
>
> Message:  Function mcrypt_get_block_size() is deprecated
>
> Filename: paytm_lib/encdec_paytm.php

Comment: Please check this thread and in last they have provided a solution too:-https://github.com/anandsiddharth/laravel-paytm-wallet/issues/8   .... You can read this thread too if problem not solved:- https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/issues/1052

Comment: They have used openssl_encrypt() , I need it using non ssl connection.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory, the `mcrypt` library is [deprecated since PHP7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php). Generally speaking you have two options. Either stop using this library (or upgrade it?) and use something contemporary (prefered). Or [instruct PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) to ignore deprecated error if you cannot afford to change the library for some reason.